# how can I get instance variables defined in a file required within a route handler into the context into the template's context?

Tags: ruby, templates, sinatra, web-frameworks

Basically I have a file, `foo.rb`  In that file, I define @bar.  Then in my `app.rb` I have something like

```
get '/' do
  load 'foo.rb'
  haml :index
end
```

and in `index.haml` I try to use `@bar` but `@bar` is *nil*.  =(

Is there a way to do this?  Basically, I'd like to break up code into separate files and load them within each route handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you can use 'helpers' that give you a great way to separate you business logic. In your case it would be look like this:

```
**** foo.rb ****
helpers do
  def bar
    "Hello, world!"
  end
end

**** app.rb ****
require 'sinatra'
require 'path/to/your/foo.rb'

get '/' do
  bar
end
```

That snippet will be rendered as html page with 'Hello, world' line.